# change the color of the lines in the line chart vegalite

Tags: d3.js, line, linechart, vega-lite, vega

I would like to change the color of the lines in my line chart. They are set to be automatic at the moment. Two lines represent two different points of data.
My code:

```
vegalite({
  width: 600,
  heigth: 800,
  data: { values: MeanAp },
  mark: {
    type: "line",
    interpolate: "natural"
  },
  encoding: {
    x: {
      timeUnit: "month",
      field: "month_mean",
      type: "temporal",
      title: "Month"
    },
    y: {
      aggregate: "sum",
      type: "quantitative",
      field: "amount"
    },
    color: {
      type: "nominal",
      field: "status_mean"
    }
  }
})
```

The chart below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the colors for your lines by defining a custom scale range or setting a color scheme.

For example, you could manually set the color range like this, using any valid HTML color name or hex code:

```
color: {
  type: "nominal",
  field: "status_mean"
  scale: {
    range: ["green", "blue"]
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use one of the pre-defined [Vega color schemes](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/schemes/):

```
color: {
  type: "nominal",
  field: "status_mean"
  scale: {
    scheme: "accent"
  }
}
```

A full description of available color options can be found in Vega-Lite's [Scale Range](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/scale.html#range) documentation.